# Limit the type of EC2 instance in IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I want to create and IAM policy in which the IAM user will not be able to launch any instance other than t2.micro Ubuntu in us-east-1 region. I have added the ami in IAM policybut instead of allowing just the Ubuntu ami, AWS is allowing the IAM user to launch all instances. What might be the problem

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "TheseActionsDontSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:Describe*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:RunInstances",
            "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:StartInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:196687784845:instance/ami-0885b1f6bd170450c"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Are you saying that you want to limit the **Instance Type** _AND_ restrict them to using a specific AMI? The Instance Type restriction should be placed on `RunInstances` and `ModifyInstanceAttribute`. The AMI restriction should be placed on `RunInstances`.

Answer (score 0):

this should point you in the right direction

```
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"TheseActionsDontSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "ec2:Describe*"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      },
      {
         "Sid":"TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissions",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "ec2:RunInstances",
            "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:StartInstances"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:196687784845:instance/ami-0885b1f6bd170450c",
         "Condition":{
            "ForAnyValue:StringLike":{
               "ec2:ImageType":"t2.micro"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Using this I am able to launch other amis as well, whereas I just want "ami-0885b1f6bd170450c" in us-east-1. Thanks for looking into it though. Much appreciated.

Comment: " ec2:ImageType | string like | t2.micro is not a supported condition key for this action." this seems to be the error for StartInstance, StopInstance, ec2:TerminateInstances.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `Deny` rules to disallow launching instances if the wrong instance type or the wrong ami is used. Note that I removed the `Sid` parameter as it is optional.

An explicit `Deny` rule will override any `Allow` rules. That makes it easier to disallow unwanted actions, instead of trying to carve out the allowed action. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_evaluation-logic.html#policy-eval-denyallow

Try the following:

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "ec2:Describe*"
         ],
         "Resource": "*"
      },
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "ec2:RunInstances",
            "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances",
            "ec2:StartInstances"
         ],
         "Resource": "*"
      },
      {
         "Effect": "Deny",
         "Action": [
           "ec2:RunInstances"
         ],
         "Resource": "*",
         "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
               "ec2:ImageType": "t2.micro"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "Effect": "Deny",
         "Action": [
           "ec2:RunInstances"
         ],
         "NotResource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:196687784845:instance/ami-0885b1f6bd170450c"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I tried it out and it seemed to give permission to launch every instance rather than "ami-0885b1f6bd170450c". Thanks for replying. Much appreciated.